# Decomposition of $5$ in subfield of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{25})$.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $\zeta = e^{2 \cdot \pi \cdot i  / 25}$ be a primitive 25-th root of unity and let $K$ be the (unique) subfield of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ so that $[K : \mathbb{Q}] = 5$.

(I.e., $K$ is the field fixed by the automorphisms $\zeta \mapsto \zeta, \zeta \mapsto \zeta^7, \zeta \mapsto \zeta^{18}, \zeta \mapsto \zeta^{24}$. One can prove that $K = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ with $\alpha = \zeta + \zeta^7 + \zeta^{18} + \zeta^{24}$.)

My question: How can I find the prime decomposition of $(5)$ in $K$?

My ideas so far: $5$ is ramified in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$. To be concrete, $(5) = (1-\zeta)^{20}$. By a discriminant argument, one finds that $5$ is ramified in $K$ as well. Since $K \mid \mathbb{Q}$ is Galois, there thus should be a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ in $K$ so that $\mathfrak{p}^5 = (5)$. We can lift this equation to $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$: Then $(5) = (\mathfrak{p} \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)})^5 = (1-\zeta)^{20}$, hence $\mathfrak{p}  \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)} = (1-\zeta)^{4}$. But I do not know how to proceed from here. Is it possible to describe $\mathfrak{p}$ explicitly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't it be more direct to notice that $\mathfrak{p}$ is  just the norm of $(1-\zeta)$ from $L = \mathbf{Q}(\zeta)$ to $K$? Then

$$\mathfrak{p} = (\beta) = ((1-\zeta)(1 - \zeta^7)(1-\zeta^{18})(1 - \zeta^{24}))$$

Where $\beta \in K$.

If you like, you could write

$$\beta = -2/7 \alpha^4 + 1/7 \alpha^3 + 23/7 \alpha^2 - 32/7 \alpha  + 3/7.$$

Comment: We know it will be a prime ideal, ie. $\mathfrak{p} = (1-\zeta)\mathbb{Z}[\zeta] \cap \mathcal{O}_K$ by looking at the field and ideal norm

Answer (score 1):

It's not obvious to me whether or not the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$
equals $\Bbb Z[\alpha]$. If it does, then $\mathfrak{p}=(5,\alpha-4)$.
This is still the case if $5$ does not divide the index $|\mathcal{O}_K:\Bbb Z[\alpha]|$. If
$5\mid|\mathcal{O}_K:\Bbb Z[\alpha]|$ then I will have to think again....

Comment: FWIW The minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ is $m(x)=x^5-10x^3+5x^2+10x+1$. The discriminant of $m(x)$ is $5^8\cdot7^2$. The discriminant of the cyclotomic field is $5^{35}$. So we definitely have $7\mid |\mathcal{O}_K:\Bbb Z[\alpha]|$.  I'm afraid I don't know how to compute the relative discriminant so that we might deduce $d_K$.

Comment: $5$ is totally in ramified in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$ thus so it is in $\mathcal{O}_K$, and $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is a Galois extension since $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)/\mathbb{Q}$ is abelian. Write $\mathcal{O}_K = \mathbb{Z}[f_1(\zeta),\ldots,f_m(\zeta)]$ where $f_l \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$. Thus $5 \mathcal{O}_K = \mathfrak{p}^{[K:\mathbb{Q}]}$ where $\mathfrak{p} = (5,f_1(\zeta)-f_1(1),\ldots,f_m(\zeta)-f_m(1))$